# Formatting number returned in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I need to format a number that is returned in a voting system in a js.erb file I have.  I am able to prepend a "+" sign for positive numbers when the page is initially loaded through rails (and a "-" sign for negative numbers as well), but on the javascript I am uncertain of how to add the same.  Here is my _like.js.erb:

```
$('.like')
    .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
    .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
    .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
    .on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) { $("#comment_<%= comment.id %>").html('<%=escape_javascript comment.cached_votes_score.to_s %>').hide().fadeIn(500); });

$('.unlike')
    .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
    .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
    .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
    .on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) { $("#comment_<%= comment.id %>").html('<%=escape_javascript comment.cached_votes_score.to_s %>').hide().fadeIn(500); });
```

here is my html.erb partial:

```
<%= link_to unlike_post_post_comment_path(post, comment), class: "unlike", method: :put, remote: true do %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">
        <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i></span>
    </button>
<% end %>
<%= link_to like_post_post_comment_path(post, comment), class: "like", method: :put, remote: true do %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
        <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></span>
    </button>
<% end %>
<% if comment.cached_votes_score > 0 %>
    <span class="badge like vote-score" id="comment_<%= comment.id %>"><%= "+ #{comment.cached_votes_score}" %></span>
<% elsif comment.cached_votes_score < 0 %>
    <span class="badge like vote-score" id="comment_<%= comment.id %>"><%= "- #{comment.cached_votes_score.abs}" %></span>
<% else %>
    <span class="badge like vote-score" id="comment_<%= comment.id %>"><%= comment.cached_votes_score %></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show us the .html.erb file that you have the voting element (`#comment_<%= comment.id %>`)?

Comment: Updated original post to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see what you need. Change your code in your `ajax:success` callback to something like this:

```
$("#comment_<%= comment.id %>").html("<%= comment.cached_votes_score > 0 ? "+ #{comment.cached_votes_score.to_s}" : (comment.cached_votes_score < 0 ? "- #{comment.cached_votes_score.to_S}" : comment.cached_votes_score.to_s) %>");
```

Doesn't look pretty and you might have to work the quotes a bit (change " to /"), but that works for what you want.

Edit:

Another way to do it is to use [sprintf](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf). Not sure if you specifically want a space in between the + and the number, but try this:

```
$("#comment_<%= comment.id %>").html("<%= sprintf("%+d", comment.cached_votes_score) %>");
```

Comment: Edited it a tiny bit (added escaped_javascript) and a quote or two and we are good to go.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool! If that works (I'm guessing you used the first method), don't forget to mark it as answered.